# how can I map a shortcut to an arbitrary key sequence in xmonad or xwindows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, xmonad

I have a shortcut I would like to perform on any chrome instances whilst using xmonad (or a generic xwindows solution would be handy)

basically its the same keysequence for chrome/firefox/opera to "detatch current browser tab and send to screen n"

The pseudocode

```
//detach current tab and send to screen n
if current_window_is_browser
     map <alt-t>6 <ctrl-l><ctrl-c><ctrl-w><ctrl-n><ctrl-v><enter><alt-shift-6>
```

I've fooled around with tab detach scripts but they don's seem to be current (esp chrome). At any rate I want the same command for all of the browsers.

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml)

Install via apt: sudo apt-get install xdotool

with xdotool you can do:

```
xdotool key alt+t 6 ...
```

of course you could save the xdotool as a script and execute it with a keybinding in xmonad.